# Magento sending SMS upon creating shipment

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Banging my head for the last two days but unable to achieve this. Help!!

Whenever a shipment email is communicated I want to trigger a code which will send a SMS to the customer informing him/her that his order has been dispatched and also communicate the tracking number.

The code will be something like this:

```
<?php 
$url = "http://www.abcde.in/binapi/pushsms.php?usr=xyz&pwd=abc&sndr=MEGYTR&ph=8888829554&text=This is test. MegaYtr&rpt=1";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Questions:
1) From where do I run this code?

2) How do I get additional info like Order Number, Customer Name, Grand Total & Tracking Number. I had done something similar for sending SMS when customer places order at that I used this code:

```
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$shipping_address_data = $order_details->getShippingAddress();
$first_name = $shipping_address_data['firstname'];
$telephone = $shipping_address_data['telephone'];
$amount_paid = $order_details->total_paid;
$message = 'Dear '.$first_name.' thank you for shopping at abc.com. Your order'.$this->getOrderId().' amounting to Rs.'.$amount_paid.'is being processed.';
echo '<b>'.$message.' Please check your email for further details.</b>';
```

I am using Magento Community 1.7.0.1.

Comment: Built in functionality of this extension https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 1):

try this

i would like to give you an simple solution without need of modifying core files.
for that you need to create an observer for `SuccessAction` below is the event that will trigger your code when an order is successfull

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

this will help you in creating observer for the above event [create observer using this](http://snipplr.com/view/56959/)

one more thing i would like to add is in the controller at location `Mage/Checkout/OnepageController` search for `successAction`, this is the Action which is processed on the succes of order. Here on line `240` if you comment `$session->clear();` than you would not require to place order again and again, just by refreshing the page you can check your changes.

And lastly FYI above event will dispatch `orderId` by using that you can load the order object, for doing that the below is the code

```
//load order object
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id_from_observer);
```